# JSF 2.1 selectoneMenu with custom converter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters, selectonemenu

what I'm trying to achieve is pretty simple:

a selectoneMenu populated using an Array of an Enum.

I defined a custom converter, and i noticed a **strange** thing:

in the converter's method "getAsString" the parameter value in not an element of the array gestioneFlussiGieRRM.tipiReport but the array itself!

I haven't found anything similar googling for it.

So: what am I doing Wrong?

Thank you in advance.

My Page

```
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{gestioneFlussiGieRRM.tipo}" id="reportType">
<f:converter   converterId ="tipoReport.converter" />
       <f:selectItems  value="#{gestioneFlussiGieRRM.tipiReport}" var="t"  itemValue="#{t}" itemLabel="#{t.descrizione}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

My Managed bean:

```
private TipoReport tipo = TipoReport.StorageFacilityReport;

/* getter and setter for tipo */

/** @return the tipiReport */
public TipoReport[] getTipiReport() {
return TipoReport.values();
}
```

The Enum

```
public enum TipoReport {
StorageFacilityReport(1, "Storage Facility Report"), StorageParticipantActivityReport(2,
    "Storage Participant Activity Report"), StorageUnavailabilityReport(3, "Storage Unavailability Report");

private int     tipo;
private String  descrizione;

private TipoReport(int tipo, String descrizione) {
this.tipo = tipo;
this.descrizione = descrizione;
}

public int getTipo() {
return tipo;
}

public String getDescrizione() {
return descrizione;
}
```

}

**EDIT**:
I'm Using JSF 2.1.27 mojarra implementation

Comment: With enum arrays there should be no need for a custom converter. JSF already has a builtin enum converter. Although the described symptom is strange, try just removing the `converter` and check what happens.

Comment: @BaluC Thank you for your quick answer. I ended up trying a custom converter because I was getting a ClassCastException on every PostBack.
The problem was basically the same, the EnumConverter could not convert an Array of Enum to an Enum.

Looking at the generated HTML i noticed that every <option> tag had the same value and that value was an array toString: [Lpackage.class@hash.

I managed to get it to work without problem using a Map, but I am still curious about why it would not work with the array. 

So any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The cause of your problem is not visible in the information provided so far. When we copypaste exactly the provided code into a blank sandbox project, and remove the converter, then it works just fine for us. Have you tried reproducing the problem in a blank sandbox project?